# How to extract each value from a list of list and make a single list with different sub list values

Tags: java

I have a list containing a sub list. I want to make a new list with different sub list values, but same main list values. For example example, `[[1,2,..[[5..],[6..]]]` into `[[1,2,..[5..]],[1,2,[6]]]`.

How can I achieve this in Java?

```
List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

addresses.add(new Address("Address 1 Line 1", "Address 1 Line 2", "Address 1  town", "Address 1 city", "12345"));
addresses.add(new Address("Address 2 Line 1", "Address 2 Line 2", "Address 2 town", "Address 2 city", "22222"));
addresses.add(new Address("Address 3 Line 1", "Address 3 Line 2", "Address 3 town", "Address 3 city", "33333"));

Employee employee1 = new Employee(100, "Emp 1", addresses);

List<Address> addresses2 = new ArrayList<>();

addresses2.add(new Address("Address 4 Line 1", "Address 4 Line 2", "Address 4 town", "Address 4 city", "444444"));
addresses2.add(new Address("Address 5 Line 1", "Address 5 Line 2", "Address 5 town", "Address 5 city", "55555"));
addresses2.add(new Address("Address 6 Line 1", "Address 6 Line 2", "Address 6 town", "Address 6 city", "66666"));
```

What I actually want to achieve is that when there is a list like this

```
"employee": [
{
  "name": "adnan",
  "lname": "ahmed",
  "address": [
    {
      "state": "a",
      "city": "b"
    },
    {
      "state": "c",
      "city": "d"
    }
  ]
```

It should get converted into this

```
"employee": [
{
  "name": "adnan",
  "lname": "ahmed",
  "address": [
    {
      "state": "a",
      "city": "b"
    },
  {
  "name": "adnan",
  "lname": "ahmed",
  "address": [
    {
      "state": "c",
      "city": "d"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: What do you want? Please explain clearly? Please give an example structure of the type of list you want. Your current example is not very clear.

Comment: i have elaborated the  question

Comment: The expected JSON structure seems to be incorrect - the second `Address` mixes the fields from both `Employee` and `Address` classes.  It seems you need to convert a structure `Employee {String name, List<Address> adresses}` to `List<Employee2> {String name, Address oneAddress}`, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you're trying to get all addresses from employee object

```
    List<String> allAddressesAsString = employee1.getAddresses().stream().
                     flatMap(l -> l.addresses.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: yes but i want it to add it in the outer list

Comment: You need different java object to represent your second json structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

First implemented `Cloneable` interface in `Employee` class.

```
class Employee implements Cloneable {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private List<Address> addresses;

    // constructor

    @Override
    protected Object clone() {
        Employee person = null;
        try {
            person = (Employee) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            person = new Employee(this.id, this.name);
        }
            return person;
     }

     // getters and setters
}
```

Then you can create the `Employee` list as follows,

```
List<Employee> employees = employee.getAddresses().stream().map(address -> {
            Employee employeeCopy = (Employee) employee.clone();
            employeeCopy.setAddresses(Collections.singletonList(address));
            return employeeCopy;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```